# Using Jquery validate with two buttons in a Asp.net Form

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-validate

I have two buttons in a asp.net form. I use Jquery Validate for required field validation. Two button are one is submit and second one is login. i don't want when i click on login if a field with validation is empty it will stop page postback. I want the jquery validation only work when submit button is pressed and page postback happen.

Comment: can we have a look at what u have tried??

Comment: I have this....I use this....not work here, please post the code that you have tried so far...

Comment: Follow these links: http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/ http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/ because you didn't post your code.

Comment: Your question is off-topic without showing your code.  See items #2 and #3 on this page:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery Validator plugin is designed to work on `<form>` tags. But, asp webforms follow a single form architecture. So if you click either of the button it will submit the form and validation would be attached to this submit event by default.

There is a workaround for this and well explained in [this](http://encosia.com/asp-net-webforms-validation-groups-with-jquery-validation/) article. Please go through [it](http://encosia.com/asp-net-webforms-validation-groups-with-jquery-validation/).

Comment: Please make your answer fully self-contained.  Otherwise, when the link goes dead, your answer will be practically useless.

Answer (score -1):

Within your click handler, the mistake is that .validate() only re-initializes the plugin, it does not validate the form.

To eliminate the need to have a submit button within the form, use .valid() to trigger a validation check...

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    $("#form1").valid();
});
```

Comment: Small correction... `.validate()` only initializes the plugin the _first_ time it's called.  It does nothing on all subsequent calls... therefore there is no such thing as "re-initializing" here.  Otherwise, yes, you're correct in that `.validate()` is not the _testing_ method; that's what `.valid()` is for.